# Java - ReadObject with nio

Tags: java, serialization, nio

In a traditional blocking-thread server, I would do something like this

```
class ServerSideThread {

    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    Engine engine;

    public ServerSideThread(Socket socket, Engine engine) {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public void sendMessage(Message m) {
        out.writeObject(m);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Message m = (Message)in.readObject();
            engine.queueMessage(m,this); // give the engine a message with this as a callback
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the object can be expected to be quite large. In my nio loop, I can't simply wait for the object to come through, all my other connections (with much smaller workloads) will be waiting on me.

How can I only get notified that a connection has the entire object before it tells my nio channel it's ready?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write the object to a ByteArrayOutputStream allowing you to give the length before an object sent. On the receiving side, read the amount of data required before attempting to decode it.

However, you are likely to find it much simpler and more efficient to use blocking IO (rather than NIO) with Object*Stream

---

Edit something like this

```
public static void send(SocketChannel socket,  Serializable serializable) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) baos.write(0);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(serializable);
    oos.close();
    final ByteBuffer wrap = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());
    wrap.putInt(0, baos.size()-4);
    socket.write(wrap);
}

private final ByteBuffer lengthByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[4]);
private ByteBuffer dataByteBuffer = null;
private boolean readLength = true;

public Serializable recv(SocketChannel socket) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (readLength) {
        socket.read(lengthByteBuffer);
        if (lengthByteBuffer.remaining() == 0) {
            readLength = false;
            dataByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(lengthByteBuffer.getInt(0));
            lengthByteBuffer.clear();
        }
    } else {
        socket.read(dataByteBuffer);
        if (dataByteBuffer.remaining() == 0) {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataByteBuffer.array()));
            final Serializable ret = (Serializable) ois.readObject();
            // clean up
            dataByteBuffer = null;
            readLength = true;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The blocking IO won't scale. Because the stack thread size is constant across the JVM, each connection thread is going to be the same stack size as my engine's thread (which is going to need to be quite large.) So with even only 3000 connections, this puts me at 384Mb just for connections. This doesn't leave much for system, heap, and database on a 1Gb box. The cpu demands will be small enough that I could easily handle over 10000 connections, barring the memory usage.

Comment: So where I send the amount of data to read first, how would I know how much data I have queued up until... I read it?

Comment: Use a `new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream` with every object (or group of objects) That way you have no data queued. You send the length of the byte array as an `int` followed by the byte array. On the reading side, you need to read 4-byte minimum which will give you the length of the rest for the data for the object.

Comment: I understand that part. Let's say I read the 4 bytes and I get 1000. So I know I need to read 1000 bytes before I am able to read this object. How do I know when I can read those 1000 bytes without blocking?

Comment: Perhaps its time to get more memory. A server with 4 GB costs about $500 and a server with 16 GB costs about $1000. ;)

Comment: You don't know when you can read the data without blocking. However, if you have read the first four bytes, you know the rest is not far behind. If you don't want to wait you can buffer the data you have and ObjectInputStream the data when you have read the expected number of bytes.

Comment: @glowcoder, May be not the point, but it is useful to have the right tools for the job. ;)

Comment: Maybe, but it still wouldn't scale indefinately. If I had that much more memory, I'd also have more processing and bandwidth, which would allow me to scale up to 100k users on a server with nio, but would limit me to about 30k with standard blocking.

Comment: @Peter here's a thought. Would it be viable to, when I read those four bytes, use a threadpool and read the rest of the bytes there? I'd have a constant number of threads, so instead of having 1 per connection with 99% of them blocking?

Comment: So basically, I'm like "ooo I have four bytes coming in... hey next thread in line, take this stream and read an object!" with that in mind, I wouldn't even need those four bytes, I could just send a single byte that says "INCOMIIINNNGGG!!!!"

Comment: @glowcoder, with NIO, you perform a read, and it tells you how many bytes were read. You then take those bytes, and put them in a separate buffer you maintain for each connection until the required number of bytes have been accumulated. I would recommend wrapping this functionality in your own pair of input and output streams.

Comment: @Dilum I like it. I had forgotten about that. I just read it. Then I can have an ObjectInputStream on hand and pump the object-bytes into it and out pops an Object. :)

Comment: @glowcoder, I wouldn't suggest you go over 10K connections per server on managed hardware. esp. one which is so resource limited. ;)

Comment: Note: There're two subtle pitfalls one should be aware when using `new ObjectOutputStream()` with every object over a single `ObjectOutput/InputStream` pair for the entire session: First, data which only need to be sent once, such as headers and various meta-information about types, gets resent for every send. Second, common instances on the sender side become difference references when received across multiple sends.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the code above I've created a  ([GoogleCode project](https://code.google.com/p/nio-threaded-tools/))

It includes a simple unit test:

```
SeriServer server = new SeriServer(6001, nthreads);
final SeriClient client[] = new SeriClient[nclients];

//write the data with multiple threads to flood the server

for (int cnt = 0; cnt < nclients; cnt++) {
    final int counterVal = cnt;
    client[cnt] = new SeriClient("localhost", 6001);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try {
                for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < nsends; cnt2++) {
                   String msg = "[" + counterVal + "]";                       
                   client[counterVal].send(msg);
                 }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 fail();
             }
         }
         });
    t.start();
 }

 HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   int nullCounts = 0;
   for (int cnt = 0; cnt < nsends * nclients;) {
       //read the data from a vector (that the server pool automatically fills
       SeriDataPackage data = server.read();  
       if (data == null) {
              nullCounts++;
              System.out.println("NULL");
              continue;
       }

       if (counts.containsKey(data.getObject())) {
              Integer c = counts.get(data.getObject());
              counts.put((String) data.getObject(), c + 1);
        } else {
              counts.put((String) data.getObject(), 1);
        }
        cnt++;
        System.out.println("Received: " + data.getObject());
   }

   // asserts the results
   Collection<Integer> values = counts.values();
   for (Integer value : values) {
        int ivalue = value;
        assertEquals(nsends, ivalue);
        System.out.println(value);
   }
   assertEquals(counts.size(), nclients);
   System.out.println(counts.size());
   System.out.println("Finishing");
   server.shutdown();
```