# Object passing through non-blocking Java NIO sockets not always successful

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

I'm writing a program to simulate peers on a P2P network using Java NIO non-blocking sockets. The idea is to have each peer use the same code for sending and receiving messages as well as a server to allow peers to bootstrap into the network.

The problem I'm having is although up to four peers can successfully join the network and talk to each other (Ping, Pong, Query and QueryHit), when I add a fifth peer the server always reports a "StreamCorruptedException". I've checked this website as well as Java NIO code/tutorial websites for solutions, but to no avail. I understand sending objects over non-blocking sockets is not easy/ideal (especially with ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream), but I want to minimise the use of threads (also I don't want to re-write this from scratch!).

I'll show the most important methods first (message send and receive), but I can add more later if required.

Write method:

```
public void write(SelectionKey selKey){ 
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)selKey.channel();
    ArrayList<Message> queue = pending.get(channel);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try{
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Could not create object output stream. Aborting...");
        return;
    }

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){            
        Message message = queue.get(0);
        buffer.clear();
        try{
            oos.writeObject(message);
            buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());
            channel.write(buffer);
            oos.flush();
            baos.flush();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Could not parse object. Aborting...");
            queue.remove(0);
            return;
        }
        queue.remove(0);
    }
    selKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}
```

And the read method:

```
public Message read(SelectionKey selKey) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)selKey.channel();        
    Message message = null;

    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);

    int bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
    if(bytesRead > 0){
        buffer.flip();
        InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.limit());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais); //Offending line. Produces the StreamCorruptedException.
        message = (Message)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }

    return message;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
int bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
if(bytesRead > 0){
    buffer.flip();
    InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.limit());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais); //Offending line. Produces the StreamCorruptedException.
    message = (Message)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
}
```

Here you're mixing blocking and non-blocking I/O.  The buffer will not have exhaustively read from the socket, it will only have read what is available.  If you're going to take this approach you need to read all of the data into the buffer first.

Comment: The same problem at the other end: `channel.write(buffer)` might not write the whole buffer, if the channel is set to nonblocking mode.

Comment: So I'm guessing I need to find out what the size of Message will be and keep reading into the buffer until it is full? If so, do I have to send two messages: one containing the size of Message and then the message itself?

Comment: Yes, that would work.  That is the out-of-band data mentioned in another answer; the stream itself wasn't designed to operate on parts and pieces of an encoded object (which is essentially what is happening).  Apparently, the extra peer added enough data that previously contiguous blocks of data are now being segmented.

Comment: I was looking at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862971/java-readobject-with-nio) which is putting the size of the message infront of the message so that, on the receiving side, two buffers are used: one to read the length and another created with `length` size to read the message. I tried to do the same, but without the `readLength` boolean (as in do two `Socket.read`s one after the other) and I still got a `StreamCorruptionException`. I was hoping to do everything in one message rather than two, but it looks like I have no choice? Can I not perform two reads at once?

Comment: @Mike: If you want to do that, you cannot create the `ObjectInputStream` before all the bytes have been read.  In other words, you would need to read all the bytes into a temporary buffer, and when the number of bytes read equals the length according to the beginning field of the message, then you can use the ObjectInputStream.  But let me ask you this:  What was the reason you wanted to go for non-blocking I/O in the first place?  It definitely complicates things and it seems like you're hoping to read all in one chunk anyway.  I would explore just using normal blocking I/O on N threads.

Comment: @Mark: The reason is because this program should allow hundreds of peers to run on one computer. (Apart from this program being a teaching aid for classes with each computer as a peer, it can act as a simulator as well.) Since each peer has to communicate with each other (as well as the server), this leads to 100^100 connections. With this many of connections, I want to minimise the use of threads or the computer will grind to a halt. I figured if I use non-blocking sockets, I can eliminate the need for thousands of threads.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume that your read will return the entire object in one chunk.  You need an "out-of-band" (well, out of ObjectStream band) protocol to insure that you are receiving complete messages, assembling messages from read chunks as necessary.  For non-blocking this will be a good deal more complicated than what you have now.