# How to stop a Thread waiting for input

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a Listener Thread on my program, which is just waiting for an Input from Server. So he receive a message, put it in a queue, and wait for another one. Because of this fact, it can't be closed on the way proposed in other similar subjects, because he needs to receive a message from the server before testing the While condition.

Here it is:

```
public class Listener implements Runnable{

    private Socket socket; 
    private ObjectInputStream ois;


    public Listener(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!socket.isClosed()) {
                String type = ois.readUTF();
                System.out.println("received: " +type);
                main.queue.put(type);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, when i close the socket, the ois.readUTF will throw an EOFException. 
What can i do to properly stop this stream without getting this exception?

The only way i found is, when the client want to stop the connection (and so close the socket), he can send a message to the server (like "goodbye" or whatever), and then the server will answer "goodbye" too, and when my listener receive this goodbye, he'll close the socket, which will make him go out of the while loop and stop. I think it should be working well. But i would like to know if there's another way to do that (somehow i'm not very pleased with my idea).

Comment: Interrupt the thread and/or close the connection.

Comment: Did you read the post? The question is precisely HOW to do that, knowing that ois.read is blocking until it gets an input. So closing the connection will just make him throw a EOFException.

Comment: Which is exactly what it should do. Then it won't be blocking on the read anymore. I read your post, but you obviously don't understand the help I'm giving you.

Comment: The question is "What can i do to properly stop this stream **without getting this exception**?". Thought it was clear.

Comment: But you just think it's bad because there's an exception. I'm telling you that it's perfectly normal to do it that way. You're saying "properly", which implies that this isn't the proper way. I'm telling you that you're wrong.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, i'm saying "properly" to say i want a proper way, but other that having this exception. I don't think the exception is bad, i'm actually glad that she's here, but i just want to find another proper way, without using that exception.

Comment: With Basic IO, which you're using this is the proper way. Closing the socket or interrupting the thread will get you out of the blocking call. Non-blocking IO gives you alternatives, but you're not using it and it's a lot more complicated than Basic IO. I know you you asked "without getting this exception", but what people ask isn't always what people really need or even want, they just don't know it themselves.

Comment: yeah, this is good, but in fact i'm already using this exception in the case where the server close the socket. I wanted another way for the case where the client close the socket. Althought it may not be really important to distinguish those case...the socket get closed in both way. So i guess i can keep it like that. Thank you.

Comment: That's why you still need flags. Especially with `InterruptedException`. You can't know why the thread was interrupted, but you can check a flag like `isClosed` in the catch block to determine whether you should reconnect, shut down the thread etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use non blocking IO API provided by [NIO API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html). This would require to do non trivial changes to this piece of code.

The easy way would be to set some flag `isFinishing` before closing the socket. Then the waiting thread should check if the flag is set in catch clause. If it is the case then it can safely ignore `EOFException`. If you go this way make sure `isFinishing` is properly synchronized (either volatile or better a `CountDownLatch`).

Comment: Hum, ok...i don't think i can use NIO API, i really need an ObjectInputStream here and i have no idea how this will work with nio (and sadly no time to learn it).  I also thought about catching a flag, but i still prefer my solution than that. I guess i'll stick with my idea then.

Comment: It's not as simple as with blocking API but you [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862971/java-readobject-with-nio) `ObjectInputStream`